# Python - I change the variable, but the output is staying the same

Tags: python

I have set up a very basic calculation to work out compound interest over a variable number of years. I define the variables like this:

```
>>> initial = 100
>>> rate = 1.1
>>> years = 5
>>> final = (initial*rate**years)
```

I think this bit of code is fine, as I can get the correct answer like so:

```
>>> print(final)
161.051...
```

Ok so now I am want to assign a new value to the variable, and try again with the new variable. So I do this:

```
>>> rate = 1.05
>>> print(final)
161.051...
```

No matter how many times I re-assign the variables, the answer will stay the same.

What is it I am missing? I have some vague recollection of something called pointer arithmetic and I'm wondering if that is at all relevant, but I can't seem to find the answer any where.

Comment: The `basic` tag is for the language named BASIC, not for questions that are simple.

Comment: ...and if you want automatic recalculation (reactive programming, &c), Python's the wrong language for the job. Setting `final=(initial*rate**years)` assigns a *value* to `final`, it doesn't establish a *relationship*.

Comment: `final` is defined with your first numbers, if you input the line `final=(initial*rate**years)` again, this should work

Comment: You haven't "set up a very basic calculation", you have *performed* a very basic calculation. The code `final=(initial*rate**years)` means "calculate the current value of `initial` multiplied by the current value of `rate` to the power of the current value of `years` and assign the result to the variable `final`". This is only done once, for the values that were in place at the time of the assignment to `final`. Look into how to define functions if you want something that is recalculated every time you call it.

Comment: the value of the  variable 'final' stays the same because variables are addresses that holds information you set. If you haven't reset any info you save on that address, it wont change. You need to recall the code: final=(initial * rate * years)to reinitialize the *new* value of final using the *new* value of rate. Changing a variable doesn't mean it changes all previous declaration using that variable ;)

Comment: _"[...]Python's the wrong language for the job. "_ - Just out of curiosity, what would you say the _right_ language for the job is?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. I'm curious as well, what language would you suggest

Comment: @DavidScarlett Thanks David! So if I want something to be recalculated each time, would (at)property be the way to do it?

Comment: @BigDog Properties can only be used with class instances, which means you would need to implement a class in order to be able to use them. A function is definitely the easiest solution. I'll add an answer showing examples.

Comment: @BigDog, I don't actually suggest a different language. I suggest *not* expecting automatic recalculation. :)

Comment: @ChristianDean, to be clear, the wrong language **if** one wanted to set up an association that would be automatically recalculated, and if one values that ability more than one the things that Python does well. mathomatic comes immediately to mind -- this is within the realm of other, fancier CAS tools and languages as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following from comments on question, the easiest way to have something recalculated like this is to define a function that performs the calculation.

E.g.

```
def calculate_final_loan_principal(initial, rate, years):
    return initial*rate**years
```

It can then be called like this:

```
>>> calculate_final_loan_principal(initial=100, rate=1.1, years=5)
161.05100000000004
>>> calculate_final_loan_principal(initial=100, rate=1.05, years=5)
127.62815625000003
```

The parameter names were included there for clarity, but aren't actually needed when calling a function:

```
>>> calculate_final_loan_principal(100, 1.05, 5)
127.62815625000003
```

Or, if you define a class, then you can use properties. I'd consider this overkill, but OP specifically asked about it.

```
class CompoundInterestLoan:
    def __init__(self, initial, rate, years):
        self.initial = initial
        self.rate = rate
        self.years = years

    @property
    def final(self):
        return self.initial*self.rate**self.years
```

You then need to create an instance of the class in order to use it:

```
>>> loan = CompoundInterestLoan(initial=100, rate=1.1, years=5)
>>> loan.final
161.05100000000004
>>> loan.rate = 1.05
>>> loan.final
127.62815625000003
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have 2 buckets of paint: red and blue. You take some paint from each and mix it together in 3rd bucket. Awesome! Now you have additional, violet color. Now you replace red paint bucket with green paint bucket. Will color of 3rd bucket change? No, why would it? You didn't touch it after you mixed the colors.

Now let's talk about your code. You never change the 'final' variable after multiplication, you just changed one of it's factors. So to note the change you have to multiply again:

```
>>>rate=1.05
>>>final=(initial*rate**years)
>>>print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why will the value of final change when you didn't calculate it again!
After assigning the new value of rate you need to calculate the value of final again. Then only python will calculate the new value of final.

```
>>>rate=1.05
>>>final=(initial*rate**years)
>>>print(final)
127.62815625
```